# Howto Write to the GPIO Pin of the CM108 Chip in Linux?

Tags: linux, hid

The CM108 from C-Media has 4 GPIO pin that you can access via a hid interface.

Using the generic write function in Windows I was able to write to the gpio pins.

However I'm trying to do the same thing in Linux without success.

The linux kernel detect the device as a hidraw device.

Note: I was able to read from the device, just not write. (I've run the app as root just to make sure it wasn't a permission issue).

Comment: Did you check if the Linux driver supports writes to the device at all?

Answer (score 3):

I got this working, here's how.

I needed to create a new linux hid kernel mod. (it wasn't that hard)/*

```
/*
 * Driver for the C-Media 108 chips
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2009 Steve Beaulac <steve@sagacity.ca>
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation, version 2.
 */

/*
 * This driver is based on the cm109.c driver
 */

#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/hid.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

#define DRIVER_VERSION "20090526"
#define DRIVER_AUTHOR "Steve Beaulac"
#define DRIVER_DESC "C-Media 108 chip"

#define CM108_VENDOR_ID 0x0d8c
#define CM108_PRODUCT_ID 0x000c

#ifdef CONFIG_USB_DYNAMIC_MINORS
#define CM108_MINOR_BASE 0
#else
#define CM108_MINOR_BASE 96
#endif

/*
 * Linux interface and usb initialisation
 */

static int cm108_hid_probe(struct hid_device *hdev, const struct hid_device_id *id)
{
    int ret;

    ret = hid_parse(hdev);
    if (ret) {
        dev_err(&hdev->dev, "parse failed\n");
        goto error;
    }

    ret = hid_hw_start(hdev, HID_CONNECT_HIDRAW);
    if (ret) {
        dev_err(&hdev->dev, "hw start failed\n");
        goto error;
    }
    return 0;

error:
    return ret;
}

static struct hid_device_id cm108_device_table[] = {
    { HID_USB_DEVICE (CM108_VENDOR_ID, CM108_PRODUCT_ID) },
    /* you can add more devices here with product ID 0x0008 - 0x000f */
    { }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE (hid, cm108_device_table);

static struct hid_driver hid_cm108_driver = {
    .name = "cm108",
    .id_table = cm108_device_table, 
    .probe = cm108_hid_probe,
};

static int hid_cm108_init(void)
{
    return hid_register_driver(&hid_cm108_driver);
}

static void hid_cm108_exit(void)
{
    hid_unregister_driver(&hid_cm108_driver);   
}

module_init(hid_cm108_init);
module_exit(hid_cm108_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR(DRIVER_AUTHOR);
MODULE_DESCRIPTION(DRIVER_DESC);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

used This makefile

```
obj-m += cm108.o
```

and compile the module

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/ M=`pwd` EXTRAVERSION="-generic" modules

sudo make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/ M=`pwd` EXTRAVERSION="-generic" modules_install

depmod -a
```

I had to modify the modules.order file so that my module would get queried before the generic hid linux module.

This modules make sure that the hidraw uses Interface 2.

Then I can use fopen to read and write to the GPIO pin of the CM108 chip.

**BTW:** when writing you need to write 5byte the 1st byte is used for the HID_OUTPUT_REPORT

Answer (score -1):

Most hardware in Linux is accessible as a file. If the driver created a hardware node for it on the file-system, you're in luck. You will be able to write to it using regular file routines. Otherwise, you may need to do some assembly magic, which may require you to write a kernel module to do it.

Comment: Correct, I'm opening the device with the open system call, and then writing to it using the write system call. 

I'm connecting the the /dev/hidraw device.

Comment: I've been monitoring the usb bus using "Sniffer for USB (on win32)" and the kernel debug in linux. I can see that when from the Packets that I'm not talking to the correct Interface on Linux. 

Windows send the message to Interface 2 and linux to interface 0. The weird thing is that Linux reports the HID being on Interface 2 (using lsusb -v)

Comment: So, I guess that you've isolated the problem. I'm guessing that the standard `fopen` defaults to opening interface 0. Sometimes, a USB device creates multiple /dev entries. You may want to create a new question to ask about this specifically - accessing other interfaces.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a complete example of how to write to the CM108/CM119 GPIO pins on Linux.

https://github.com/wb2osz/direwolf/blob/dev/cm108.c

You don't need to run as root or write your own device driver.

I have the opposite problem.  I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing on Windows.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable.